# Value labels to be created using data from another data set

Tags: sas

I am having two data sets. The first data set has airport codes (JFK, LGA, EWR) in a variable 'airport'. The second dataset has the list of all major airports in the world. This dataset has two variables 'faa' holding the FAA Code (like JFG, LGA, EWR) and 'name' holding the actual name of the airport (John. F Kennedy, Le Guardia etc.).

My requirement is to create value labels for in the first data set, so that instead of airport code, the actual name of the airport comes up. I know I can use custom formats to achieve this. But can I write SAS code which can read the unique airport codes, then get the names from another data set and create a value label automatically?

PS: Other wise, the only option I see is to use MS Excel to get the unique list of FAA codes in dataset 1, and then use VLOOKUP to get the names of the airports. And then create one custom format by listing each unique FAA code and the airport name.

Comment: You can create formats from a dataset using the `cntlin` option in `proc format`.  There are plenty of examples on here or other sites. Have a look at those, give it a go and come back on here if your code doesn't work.
Tip : extract the distinct list of codes and names by joining the 2 tables, then use that as the base for your formats

Comment: @Longfish that's not required if the OP has a lookup table, a join would negate the need for a format in the first place.  I would second a format, and this question doesn't meet the SO requirements. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Labells are for variable names in SAS, formats for for variable values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, consider if it is really a format what is needed. For example, you may just do a left join to retrieve the column (airport) name from table2 (FAA-Name table).

Anyway, I believe the following macro does the trick:

Create auxiliary tables:

```
data have1;
input airport $;
datalines;
a
d
e
;
run;

data have2;
input faa $ name $;
datalines;
a aaaa
b bbbb
c cccc
d dddd
;
run;
```

Macro to create Format:

```
%macro create_format;

    *count number of faa;
    proc sql noprint;
    select distinct count(faa) into:n
    from have2;
    quit;

    *create macro variables for each faa and name;
    proc sql noprint;
    select faa, name
    into:faa1-:faa%left(&n),:name1-:name%left(&n)
    from have2;
    quit;

    *create format;
    proc format;
    value  $airport
    %do i=1 %to &n;
        "&faa%left(&i)" = "&name%left(&i)"
    %end;
    other = "Unknown FAA code";
    run;

%mend create_format;

%create_format;
```

Apply format:

```
data want;
set have1;
format airport $airport.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "value label" is SPSS terminology.  Looks like you want to create a format. Just use your lookup table to create an input dataset for PROC FORMAT.

So if your second table looks like this:

```
data table2;
  length FAA $4 Name $40 ;
  input FAA Name $40. ;
cards;
JFK John F. Kennedy (NYC)
LGA Laguardia (NYC)
EWR Newark (NJ)
;
```

You can use this code to convert it into a dataset that PROC FORMAT can use to create a format.

```
data fmt ;
  fmtname='$FAA';
  hlo=' ';
  set table2 (rename=(faa=start name=label));
run;

proc format cntlin=fmt lib=work.formats;
run;
```

Now you can use that format with your other data.

```
proc freq data=table1 ;
  tables airport ;
  format airport faa. ;
run;
```